# Сделать поле для закрытия от индексации

Tags: php, битрикс

Как сделать поле для закрытия от индексации для элементов разделов? Есть код в котором не совсем правильное условие. Не пойму, что убрать, а что добавить в условие.

```
    $rsElement = CIBlockElement::GetList(
        $arOrder  = array("SORT" => "ASC"),
        $arFilter = array(
            "ACTIVE"    => "Y",
            "IBLOCK_ID" => $arParams["IBLOCK_ID"],
            "ID" => $ElementIDх,
        ),
        false,
        false,
        $arSelectFields = array("ID", "NAME", "IBLOCK_ID", "CODE","PROPERTY_ROBOTS")
    );
    
    while ($arElement = $rsElement->fetch()) {
        if ($arElement["PROPERTY_ROBOTS_VALUE"]) {
            $APPLICATION->SetPageProperty('robots', $arElement["PROPERTY_ROBOTS_VALUE"]);
        }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Обычно это делается через добавление свойства элемента типа чекбокс "Закрыть от индексации". И затем непосредственно при выводе в шаблоне проверяете значение свойства и выводите нужный тег

```
if ($arResult["PROPERTIES"]["NOINDEX"] == "Y") {
  ?><noindex><?
}
```

Вместо noindex могут быть любые другие теги.

Comment: Спасибо, вопрос уже был решен)